# Getting error while updating android studio to 2.3 Beta

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, auto-update

I was updating android studio to `2.3 Beta 2`

[image]

---

After that I got the below error :

[image]

Please help I am now stuck how to do update.

Comment: Click on `Cancel` and retry maybe some issue in network or in system.